# Append Two Dataframes Together (Pandas, Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to append/join(?) two different dataframes together that don't share any overlapping data.

DF1 looks like

```
  Teams        Points
  Red            2
  Green          1
  Orange         3
  Yellow         4
  ....    
  Brown          6
```

and DF2 looks like

```
  Area         Miles
   2            3
   1            2
  ....
   7            12
```

I am trying to append these together using

```
 bigdata = df1.append(df2,ignore_index = True).reset_index()
```

but I get this

```
  Teams        Points
  Red            2
  Green          1
  Orange         3
  Yellow         4   
                    Area         Miles
                     2            3
                     1            2
```

How do I get something like this?

```
 Teams          Points      Area     Miles
  Red            2           2         3
  Green          1           1         2
  Orange         3
  Yellow         4
```

EDIT: in regards to Edchum's answers, I have tried merge and join but each create somewhat strange tables.  Instead of what I am looking for (as listed above) it will return something like this:

```
 Teams          Points      Area     Miles
  Red            2           2         3
  Green          1           
  Orange         3           1         2
  Yellow         4
```

Comment: try `pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: I think you see this because your indices are not contiguous so for df1 it's probably something like 0,1,2,3 but df2 it's 0,2 can you confirm this is the case and I will update my answer

Comment: OK, what you have to do is reindex or reset the index so they align

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) and pass param `axis=1`:

```
In [4]:

pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
Out[4]:
    Teams  Points  Area  Miles
0     Red       2     2      3
1   Green       1     1      2
2  Orange       3   NaN    NaN
3  Yellow       4   NaN    NaN
```

[`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join) also works:

```
In [8]:

df1.join(df2)
Out[8]:
    Teams  Points  Area  Miles
0     Red       2     2      3
1   Green       1     1      2
2  Orange       3   NaN    NaN
3  Yellow       4   NaN    NaN
```

As does [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge):

```
In [11]:

df1.merge(df2,left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
Out[11]:
    Teams  Points  Area  Miles
0     Red       2     2      3
1   Green       1     1      2
2  Orange       3   NaN    NaN
3  Yellow       4   NaN    NaN
```

**EDIT**
In the case where the indices do not align where for example your first df has index `[0,1,2,3]` and your second df has index `[0,2]` this will mean that the above operations will naturally align against the first df's index resulting in a `NaN` row for index row `1`. To fix this you can reindex the second df either by calling `reset_index()` or assign directly like so: `df2.index =[0,1]`.

Comment: Hi Ed, I've actually tried each of those solutions and each sort of accomplishes what I need but with limitations -- see my updates of the original question!  Thank you